# When using _redirect() in zend address bar not show the new url

Tags: php, zend-framework

First I want to clear something about me is that I am new to PHP and Zend.

I am developing a site using zend framework and here is a action call successAction....

```
public function successAction()
{
    $responseParams= $this->_request->getParam('responseparams');
    if (isset($responseParams)){
        $pgResArray = explode("|", $responseParams);        
        if ($pgResArray[1] == 'SUCCESS') {
            switch ($pgResArray[4]) {
                case 'xyz':
                    $this->_redirect('/xyz');
                    break;
                case 'pqr':
                    $this->_redirect('/pqr');
                    break;
                case 'abc':
                    $this->_redirect('/abc');
                    break;
            }
        }
    }


}
```

When the payment is successfully made by client the server throws the success flag to my site and I decided where to redirect now.

Every redirect url have some soap request.

My problem is that when I come back from payment gateway, address bar shows the url of payment gateway, but in the background all process done.

Redirect is working well but not shows on screen.

How to solve this...

Second thing what I want is that when I requesting to the soap server the screen will show processing image.

Comment: Notice: if (isset($responseParams)) always will be true because you set $responseParams value one line above :) what you want to use here is is_null

Comment: My question is not about isset or is_null, but its about redirect. When response come from payment gateway the url redirects according to  conditions and soap request is executed. At this time the url shown in the address bar is of payment gateway not the redirected url...

Answer (score 0):

you may need to set the `exit` option on the [action utility method _redirect()](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.action.html#zend.controller.action.utilmethods), otherwise you may wish to look into using the [action helper redirector()](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.redirector) as it has more available functionality.

> *Second thing what I want is that when I requesting to the soap server
>   the screen will show processing image.*

This function is usually achieved using javascript, you may wish to explore the [jquery javascript library](http://jquery.com/) as a bit of a javascript short cut.

Comment: but according to [action utility method _redirect()](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.action.html#zend.controller.action.utilmethods) exit will cleanly close any open sessions and perform the redirect... And I have session value. Is there any way to load full dom means controller, action and view(.phtml) before redirecting?

Comment: yes, in short it will redirect with a new request. No baggage from the old request. It shouldn't bother any persistent sessions only temporary ones. If you want to preserve all of the baggage try using the _forward() utility method.